# Menu com border

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que contém um menu com border gostaria que o menu ficasse assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não estou conseguindo deixar a borda assim e nem redonda olha como esta irei colocar meu css e html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="pagamento">
                       <button class="dropbtn">Parcelas</button><br/>
                       <p class="preco">29,90</p>
                       </h:panelGroup>

    .preco{
     margin-left: 20px;
      }

      .pagamento{

     border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
     margin-left: 580px;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Não sei bem trabalhar com XHTML, mas é assim que eu faria.

```
.preco {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.pagamento {
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;

    border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropbtn{
    margin: 10px;
}

<div class="pagamento">
<button class="dropbtn">Parcelas</button><br/>
<p class="preco">29,90</p>
</div>
```